# Block direct access to port contents on port 3838, shiny

Tags: .htaccess, shiny, shiny-server

I have a shiny server listening on port 3838. I would like to block direct access to

```
http://www.mywebsite.com:3838
```

which reveals the shiny files and directories. Any time I try to block access via htaccess, I end up blocking all access to the site. Is there any easy way to get this task completed?

Comment: If you block all direct access, how do you expect to access anything on the site at all?

Comment: All direct access to the port. I didn't say I would like to block all access to the site. Thank you for your insight Jon.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have set up a proxy that is listening to localhost, you can set your shiny server to only serve localhost in `/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf` like so:

```
server{
    listen 3838 127.0.0.1;

    location / {
    site_dir /srv/shiny-server;
    log_dir /var/log/shiny-server;
    directory_index on;
    }
}
```

This should block anyone getting around your proxy going direct to `:3838`